# Set "Away" Status on Several Apps at Once

Tags: macos, skype, irc, applescript, adium

This question is slightly born out of laziness, but here goes anyway.

I use the following apps on OSX:

- Skype
- Adium
- Linkinus

On each, I have an automated status change that triggers after being idle for 30 or so.  However, if I'm leaving for an extended period of time, I want to go ahead and set the status on all three.  It isn't a whole lot of work to do this manually on all three, but ideally I'd like to make this one keystroke.

What should I do to start this?  Should I figure out how to manipulate each one using some applescript and then bind the resulting script to a key?  Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I figure out how to manipulate each one using some applescript and then bind the resulting script to a key?

Yes.

Here's a start:

```
tell application "Adium"
   go away (every account)
end tell

tell application "Skype"
   send command "SET USERSTATUS AWAY" script name "My Script"
end tell
```

Comment: the above works for skype... for adium I receive the following:

`error "Can’t set «class Psts» to «constant EstaSawy»." number -10006 from «class Psts»`.

Adium version is 1.3.10, if that matters.

Comment: @whaley Sorry, guess the Adium dictionary has changed. Edited my answer.

Comment: Yup, that Adium applescript works now.  I'll accept and upvote since I doubt I'll get any responses here specific to Linkinus.